# UDP Read/Write using different ports

Tags: java, udp, datagram

Is is possible to use the same DatagramSocket object to read and write using two different ports? I need to receive on port X and write on port X+1. Currently what I'm doing:

```
sock = new DatagramSocket(5000);

byte[] buffer = new byte[DataAdapterFB1.HEADER_SIZE + DataAdapterFB1.MAX_DATA_BYTES];
DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
sock.receive(incoming);
```

And later:

```
dp = new DatagramPacket(send.getBytes(), send.getBytes().length, DataAdapterFB1.ccuAddr, 5001);
sock.send(dp);
```

I don't see any of the output from the send packets on wireshark.

I have also tried:

```
sock = new DatagramSocket();

byte[] buffer = new byte[DataAdapterFB1.HEADER_SIZE + DataAdapterFB1.MAX_DATA_BYTES];
DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,DataAdapterFB1.localhost, 5000);
sock.receive(incoming);

dp = new DatagramPacket(send.getBytes(), send.getBytes().length, DataAdapterFB1.Addr, 5001);
sock.send(dp);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I was able to get it to work using 2 datagramsocket objects. (Read one binds the port on the declaration, Write one does not). But want to know if I can do it with a single one.

Comment: Have you tried rebinding the socket? You will have to bind it to 5000 when you receive and 5001 when you send but that will allow you to use the same object. http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#bind(java.net.SocketAddress)

Comment: No it is not possible, and your requirement is suspect as well. It is wasteful of a port. What is the reason for this strange design?

Comment: @arynaq Your own citation shows that it is not possible.

Comment: It is the source hardware that requires this EJP. Not my choice. I just need to write an interface for it...

Comment: I find that hard to believe. It can be rather difficult to obtain two adjacent ports: often impossible. I would double-check the requirement. It doesn't seem very likely that a piece of hardware would really rely on an infeasible solution at the peer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. 2 separate objects need to be used to use separate ports.